# Using constants for annotation parameters in java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

1. Why does it have to defined as public static final?
2. Why do I have do I have to import them since they're def in the current class?

Is it because in @interface you can only use public static final fields?

And does the import has to do something with optimization?

i.e.

```
**import static db.Rezervare.FINDALL;**
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rezervari")
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(name = **FINDALL**, query = "SELECT r FROM Rezervare r ORDER BY r.nume")
)
public class Rezervare {

    **public static final String FINDALL = "Rezervare.findAll";**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because annotation values are interpreted by the compiler, not at runtime, they must be compile-time constants; `FINDALL` doesn't have to be `public`, but it does need to be `static final` to make it a constant.

The annotation itself is technically outside the class that it's applied to, so the class's member isn't inside it. You could theoretically have multiple class definitions in a single file (the JLS recommends that compilers disallow this, and all of the Java compilers I know do), and so the specific name is required.